# Is it possible to cast a trait object to another trait object?

Tags: dynamic, casting, rust

I tried the following code:

```rust
trait TraitA {
    fn say_hello(&self) {
        self.say_hello_from_a();
    }
    fn say_hello_from_a(&self);
}

trait TraitB {
    fn say_hello(&self) {
        self.say_hello_from_b();
    }
    fn say_hello_from_b(&self);
}

struct MyType {}

impl TraitA for MyType {
    fn say_hello_from_a(&self) {
        println!("Hello from A");
    }
}

impl TraitB for MyType {
    fn say_hello_from_b(&self) {
        println!("Hello from B");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a: Box<dyn TraitA> = Box::new(MyType {});
    let b: Box<dyn TraitB>;

    a.say_hello();
    b = a;
    b.say_hello();
}
```

I get the following compilation error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:34:9
   |
34 |     b = a;
   |         ^ expected trait `TraitB`, found trait `TraitA`
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::boxed::Box<dyn TraitB>`
              found struct `std::boxed::Box<dyn TraitA>`
```

I declared two traits and a type called `MyType` and implemented both traits for `MyType`. I created a new trait object `TraitA` of type `MyType` which I called `a`. Since `a` also implements `TraitB`, I thought it should be able to be casted as `TraitB`.

I haven't figured out if it's even possible. If it is, how can I cast trait object `a` into `TraitB`?

In C++, I would use something similar to `std::dynamic_pointer_cast<TraitB>(a);` for the same purpose.

Here's an example of a case where I could use lateral casting: I have a struct with some data inside that represents some real life entity:

```rust
struct MyType {
    a: i32,
    b: i32,
}
```

Instances of this type can be used in at least two different parts of the code base. On both parts I need a behavior called `get_final_value`.

The interesting part is that `get_final_value` should respond differently depending on who called it.

- Why don't I split the type into two different ones?: Technically, by design, `a` and `b` belong together, not to say that `get_final_value()` uses both values to compute the result.
- Why not use generics/static dispatch? Because `MyType` is just one example. In the real case I have different structs, all of them implementing both traits in different ways.
- Why not use `Any` trait? To be honest, I didn't know of it's existence until recently. I don't recall *The Rust Programming Language* mentioning it. Anyway, it seems you need to know the concrete type to do a cast from `Any` to that concrete type and then to the trait object.

Comment: Would you really use a dynamic cast in C++ for casting _laterally_? I can see that you can use it to downcast to a concrete type, but I have never encountered a use case for a lateral cast. For what it's worth, [downcasting can be achieved using the `Any` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/index.html?search=downcast).

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how you're using these values and how you want to use them with `get_final_value`? One option for instance would before `get_final_value` to accept anything that implements some third trait, and then both `TraitA` and `TraitB` could expose a function to convert them into that third type.

Comment: On the point about `Any` - this uses code which lives inside Any to perform downcasting. Rust still doesn't natively support downcasting, that is a separate thing. Whoever has written Any has essentially written some Rust code to emulate downcasting, since it isn't supported. Also, Rust supports upcasting from a Type to a Trait Object. (Normal pointer to Fat Pointer.) I can't say about any other forms of upcasting, such as between Trait objects, because I haven't yet looked at that in detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is to create a trait that uses both `TraitA` and `TraitB` as supertraits and provides a cast to each type:

```
trait TraitC: TraitA + TraitB {
    fn as_trait_a(&self) -> &dyn TraitA;
    fn as_trait_b(&self) -> &dyn TraitB;
}
```

Then have `MyType` implement it:

```
impl TraitC for MyType {
    fn as_trait_a(&self) -> &dyn TraitA {
        self
    }
    fn as_trait_b(&self) -> &dyn TraitB {
        self
    }
}
```

Once you do that, you can use `TraitC` for your `Box` and your program logic that uses both `TraitA` and `TraitB` together.

Sample main to show various ways to use:

```
fn test_a(a: &TraitA) {
    a.say_hello();
}
fn test_b(b: &TraitB) {
    b.say_hello();
}

fn main() {
    let c: Box<dyn TraitC> = Box::new(MyType {});

    TraitA::say_hello(&*c);
    TraitB::say_hello(&*c);

    c.as_trait_a().say_hello();
    c.as_trait_b().say_hello();

    test_a(c.as_trait_a());
    test_b(c.as_trait_b());

    let a: &dyn TraitA = c.as_trait_a();
    a.say_hello();
    let b: &dyn TraitB = c.as_trait_b();
    b.say_hello();
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6fa766d74d41e7112f871d23a2390262)

If `A` and `B` do truly belong together, this better represents that and still gives you the freedom to use them separately if you desire.

Comment: This doesn't always work apparently, for example `Arc::downcast<T>(self)` requires `T` to be `dyn Any + Send + Sync` and does not allow trait objects from supertraits. At least I don't know how.

Comment: This is very strange because inheritance hierarchies usually get *wider* as they go down, not narrower. That suggests to me that using this pattern will lead to all sorts of diamond inheritance problems, although I can't say for sure yet. It "feels" wrong to me

Answer (score 2):

Using `Box<MyType>` instead of `Box<dyn Trait>` solves this problem.

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = Box::new(MyType {});

    TraitA::say_hello(&*a);
    TraitB::say_hello(&*a);
}
```

In this case there's no need to use trait objects. Rust has a different paradigm from C++. In most cases you can usually use generic types to solve problems.
If your problem is really suitable to solve with trait objects, you can refer to the [OOP chapter in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-00-oop.html).

Comment: I know I can use MyType directly. My question goes more towards the case where you already have a trait object and want to use it as a different trait object.

Comment: You can use [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) to cast type. But can you give a scenario where this is necessary?

Comment: I added extra context on the original question about a more realistic scenario.