# How do I clone a Rc trait object and cast it to another trait object?

Tags: casting, rust, smart-pointers, trait-objects

This is a follow up question from [Rust dynamic cast trait object between different taits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55895583/rust-dynamic-cast-trait-object-between-different-taits). The solution provided there works really well when we use references for trait objects, but this time I am trying to do the same with `Rc` pointers. For example

- I have a super trait named `TraitAB` and 2 traits named `TraitA` and `TraitB`
- So when I first create a trait object of type `TraitAB` instead of using a `Box`, now I use an `Rc` pointer.
- I need a variable of type `TraitA` to be a reference of `ab`

Here I made a very minimal example:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

trait TraitAB: TraitA + TraitB {
    fn as_a(&self) -> Rc<dyn TraitA>;
    fn as_b(&self) -> Rc<dyn TraitB>;
}

trait TraitA {}
trait TraitB {}

struct MyType {}

impl TraitAB for MyType {
    fn as_a(&self) -> Rc<dyn TraitA> {
        Rc::clone(self)
    }
    fn as_b(&self) -> Rc<dyn TraitB> {
        Rc::clone(self)
    }
}

impl TraitA for MyType {}
impl TraitB for MyType {}

fn main() {
    let a: Rc<dyn TraitA>;
    let b: Rc<dyn TraitB>;
    {
        let mut ab: Rc<dyn TraitAB> = Rc::new(MyType {});
        a = ab.as_a();
        b = ab.as_b();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work though. According to the error messages:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:15:19
   |
15 |         Rc::clone(self)
   |                   ^^^^ expected struct `std::rc::Rc`, found struct `MyType`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&std::rc::Rc<dyn TraitA>`
              found reference `&MyType`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:18:19
   |
18 |         Rc::clone(self)
   |                   ^^^^ expected struct `std::rc::Rc`, found struct `MyType`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&std::rc::Rc<dyn TraitB>`
              found reference `&MyType`
```

`as_a` and `as_b` can't know self is actually an `Rc` pointer. 
Is there a way to do the cast of a cloned shared pointer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> methods `as_a` and `as_b` can't know self is actually an `Rc` pointer.

Actually, that's not true! There's [a rarely used feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25463033/4639273) that allows `self` to be taken as various standard kinds of references (`Rc<Self>`, `Box<Self>`, etc.).

That means that you can rewrite your `TraitAB` as

```
trait TraitAB : TraitA + TraitB {
    fn as_a(self: Rc<Self>) -> Rc<dyn TraitA>;
    fn as_b(self: Rc<Self>) -> Rc<dyn TraitB>;
}
```

Unfortunately, as written, `as_a` and `as_b` move `self: Rc<Self>`, since `Rc<T>` [doesn't implement `Copy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40014703/why-is-stdrcrc-not-copy) (only `Clone`). One way to fix this is to simply clone `ab` before passing it into these methods. This also means that you don't need to clone the `self` inside the method. [(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d4d5bf61a140f315763cdf7ce4c371cc)

```
let ab: Rc<dyn TraitAB> = Rc::new(MyType{});
let _a: Rc<dyn TraitA> = ab.clone().as_a();
let _b: Rc<dyn TraitB> = ab.clone().as_b();
```

Using the nightly-only feature `arbitrary_self_types`, it's possible to make `as_a` and `as_b` take self as `&Rc<Self>` (which looks weird to me since it's a reference to a reference). This allows `ab.as_a()` to be called without moving `ab`. The only problem with this approach is that `TraitAB` [is no longer object-safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.30.0/book/2018-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html?highlight=trait,object#object-safety-is-required-for-trait-objects)<sup>1</sup>, so `Rc<dyn TraitAB>` no longer works. [(playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a05607b2911aad9635f7888f124919aa).

---

1. According to [the tracking issue for arbitrary self types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44874), the object safety question is still open. I'm not really sure what the rules are right now.

Comment: I'm just a bit confused now. In the example you mentioned, does `ab.clone().as_a()` is the same as `Rc::clone(&ab).as_a()`?

Comment: Yes. It's exactly the same here. You can call trait methods as if they're methods on the type itself as long as there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `TraitAB` on `RC<MyType>`:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

trait TraitAB {
    fn as_a(&self) -> Rc<dyn TraitA>;
    fn as_b(&self) -> Rc<dyn TraitB>;
}

trait TraitA {}
trait TraitB {}

struct MyType {}

impl TraitAB for Rc<MyType> {
    fn as_a(&self) -> Rc<dyn TraitA> {
        Rc::clone(self) as Rc<dyn TraitA>
    }
    fn as_b(&self) -> Rc<dyn TraitB> {
        Rc::clone(self) as Rc<dyn TraitB>
    }
}

impl TraitA for MyType {}
impl TraitB for MyType {}

fn main() {
    let a: Rc<dyn TraitA>;
    let b: Rc<dyn TraitB>;
    {
        let mut ab: &TraitAB = &Rc::new(MyType {});
        a = ab.as_a();
        b = ab.as_b();
    }
}
```

By the way, I don't see any reason for `TraitAB` to extend `TraitA + TraitB`, but you can extend and implement `TraitA` and `TraitB` for `Rc<MyType>` as well.

[This is a working example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=511b2f97c3392722032a2271cba0fc6d) with the implemented functions for `TraitA` and `TraitB`.