# Clone an Rc<RefCell<MyType> trait object and cast it

Tags: casting, rust, traits

This question is related to [Rust: Clone and Cast Rc pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55927766/rust-clone-and-cast-rc-pointer)

Let's say I have this piece of code which works fine:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

trait TraitAB : TraitA + TraitB {
    fn as_a(self: Rc<Self>) -> Rc<dyn TraitA>;
    fn as_b(self: Rc<Self>) -> Rc<dyn TraitB>;
}

trait TraitA {}
trait TraitB {}

struct MyType {}

impl TraitAB for MyType {
    fn as_a(self: Rc<Self>) -> Rc<dyn TraitA> {self}
    fn as_b(self: Rc<Self>) -> Rc<dyn TraitB> {self}
}

impl TraitA for MyType {}
impl TraitB for MyType {}

fn main() {
    let a: Rc<dyn TraitA>;
    let b: Rc<dyn TraitB>;
    {
        let mut ab: Rc<dyn TraitAB> = Rc::new(MyType{});
        a = ab.clone().as_a();
        b = ab.clone().as_b();
    }
    // Use a and b.
}
```

Explaining the code a bit:

- I have type called `MyType` which implements `TraitA` and `TraitB`.
- The goal is to have a trait object `TraitA` be able to get casted to `TraitB` and viceversa.
- So I uses a supertrait that holds the methods to do the conversions.
- This works great for `std::Rc` smart pointers.

So far so good. But now I need a mutable reference of both `a` and `b`, but since `a` and `b`are actually the same type instance, Rust won't let me have 2 mutable references of the same thing.

So, the common pattern for this kind of problems is `std::cell::RefCell`.

Note: I believe this pattern is correct in this particular case because it's a common **interior mutability** problem. I'm not willing to actually change the reference, but the internal state of the type only.

So following that idea I changed the following lines:

```rust
trait TraitAB : TraitA + TraitB {
    fn as_a(self: Rc<RefCell<Self>>) -> Rc<RefCell<dyn TraitA>>;
    fn as_b(self: Rc<RefCell<Self>>) -> Rc<RefCell<dyn TraitB>>;
}
//...
let mut ab: Rc<RefCell<dyn TraitAB>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(MyType{}));
```

But this changes won't compile. After some reading, I found that self can only be:

- `self: Self // self`
- `self: &Self // &self`
- `self: &mut Self // &mut self`
- `self: Box<Self> // No short form`
- `self: Rc<Self> // No short form / Recently supported`

So this means I can't use

`self: Rc<RefCell<Self>>`

for the self param.

So, the main question is: Is there a way to cast an `Rc<RefCell<TraitA>>` to an `Rc<RefCell<TraitB>` ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around this issue by *not* using a receiver in `TraitAB`'s casting methods (i.e. by declaring them as *associated functions*):

```
trait TraitAB : TraitA + TraitB {
    fn as_a(it: Rc<RefCell<Self>>) -> Rc<RefCell<dyn TraitA>>;
    fn as_b(it: Rc<RefCell<Self>>) -> Rc<RefCell<dyn TraitB>>;
}
```

The trait can then be implemented as

```
impl TraitAB for MyType {
    fn as_a(it: Rc<RefCell<MyType>>) -> Rc<RefCell<dyn TraitA>> {it}
    fn as_b(it: Rc<RefCell<MyType>>) -> Rc<RefCell<dyn TraitB>> {it}
}
```

These functions can then be called using the fully qualified syntax.

```
a = TraitAB::as_a(ab.clone());
b = TraitAB::as_b(ab.clone());
```

The `TraitAB` implementation for all types will be the same. To make this implementation available for all types implementing `TraitA` and `TraitB`, you can use a generic `impl`:

```
impl<T: TraitA + TraitB + 'static> TraitAB for T {
    fn as_a(it: Rc<RefCell<T>>) -> Rc<RefCell<dyn TraitA>> {it}
    fn as_b(it: Rc<RefCell<T>>) -> Rc<RefCell<dyn TraitB>> {it}
}
```

Note that `T: 'static` because the trait objects in the function return types have an implicit `'static` lifetime bound.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=29bece160f90087629b0fc32a8ed0222)

Comment: Wow. Didn't know that a trait declaration and definition can differ in their "signature". Sometimes I have this feeling that i'm looking at very obscure corners of Rust.

Comment: I think there is a downside with this solution. Since I can't create a TraitAB trait object, this means `MyType` needs to be known at compile time. So if I have multiple types, like `MyType1`, `MyType2`, etc, declaring a variable like this won't work: `let ab: Rc<RefCell<TraitAB>>;` Do you think there could be a work around this too?

Comment: @dospro To be able to make objects of a trait, it must have at least one non-static method (i.e. method with a receiver). Simply adding a method that takes `self`, `&self` or `&mut self` to the trait will let you achieve this.

Comment: I tried adding a dummy method that receives `&self` but doesn't make any difference. I tried binding Self to sized: `fn as_a(this: Rc<RefCell<Self>>) -> Rc<RefCell<dyn TraitA>>  where Self: Sized;` but again, I get: `the size for values of type `dyn TraitAB` cannot be known at compilation time` I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Apologies, my previous comment was inaccurate. _All_ methods, not just one or more, that a trait object can be used must be non-static. If you must use a `TraitAB` trait object, it'd be better to abstract away the usage of `RefCell` by implementing `TraitA`, `TraitB` (`T: TraitX + ?Sized`) and `TraitAB` (`T: TraitA + TraitB`) for `RefCell<T>`, where a method impl for `RefCell<T>` calls the corresponding method on the  `RefCell` borrowed value. The trait objects will then be wrapped in just an `Rc<>` and not a `Rc<RefCell<>>`. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=29bece160f90087629b0fc32a8ed0222

Comment: can you please expand a bit on that last comment? What I understand is that I should make `T` be `RefCell<TheType>` instead of just the type and let rust now it's a dynamically sized type. I've been playing with the code, but I can't get it to work yet.

Comment: I sent the wrong playground link in the last comment, this is the one I wanted to send: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b2d98735a7602ec5fcce3afbf7d3cbc3. You've understood correctly; implement `TraitA` and `TraitB` on `RefCell<T>` (`T: ?Sized` to allow `T` to be a trait) so that you can do `let x: &TraitA = &RefCell::new(MyType)` (i.e. cast `RefCell<MyType>` to `TraitA`). This allows you to cast a `Rc<RefCell<T>>` to `Rc<dyn TraitA>` where `T: TraitA`. The only problem with this approach is that the `Rc` cast hides the fact that a `RefCell` is being used.